# NLTK ngrams is not working when i try to import

Tags: python, nltk

I can't seem to find an answer for why ngrams does not import when i run:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/PycharmProjects/tronc/tronc3.py", line 11, in <module>
    grams = nltk.util.ngrams(tokens, 2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ngrams'
```

Comment: It should be `from nltk import ngrams` (`nltk.__version__== 3.2.2`)

Comment: so do you mean i need to download nltk version 3.2.2?

Comment: you might need to check the version. the path to `ngrams` might be different.

Comment: In `nltk` version 3.2.2, `ngrams` _is_ defined in nltk.util (though you can also import it from the top level. But your import statement doesn't match the error you show. So make up your mind so we can try guessing what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Both import statements are fine: The one you've been using (`from nltk.util import ngrams`) and the one suggested by @titipata in a comment (`from nltk import ngrams`). The latter is just a shortcut to the former.

In any case, the exception isn't raised on the import statement. Look carefully at the traceback: The offending line is

```
grams = nltk.util.ngrams(tokens, 2)
```

on line 11 in your *tronc3.py* script.
You need to change this line to

```
grams = ngrams(tokens, 2)
```

since `ngrams` is the *name* to what you bind the imported function.

### Why is that?

There are different ways to write import statements, eg:

```
import nltk.util.ngrams
```

or

```
import nltk.util.ngrams as ngram_generator
```

or

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
```

In all cases, the last bit (everything after the last space) is how you need to refer to the imported module/class/function.
Thus, in the first case you must write `nltk.util.ngrams` every time you need it, in the second case `ngram_generator`, and in the last case simply `ngrams`.